# How do I rename a stage and job in bamboo?

Tags: bamboo

I am a bamboo noob.  How do I rename a stage and a job that have I set up in CI?  When I login as a administrator and click on the stage and the job I cannot see any rename options.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

click into your plan configuration for your plan.  On the stage you want to rename select the settings icon and then configure stage. Then rename stage.

To rename a job, click on the job and then job details. Rename as you wish.

Comment: To rename the job's key you need to clone the existing job and then delete the original one.